# How to reassociate list of graph edge indices back to a shapefile?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, shapefile

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import geopandas as gpd
import momepy
import pcst_fast
from pyproj import CRS
import fiona

roads = gpd.read_file("ala3.gpkg")
roads['length'] = roads.geometry.length
lens = list(roads.length.copy())
roads.crs = "EPSG:4326"
roads = roads.to_crs(crs='EPSG:4326')

pts = gpd.read_file("alapts.gpkg")

F = momepy.gdf_to_nx(roads, approach="primal", length="length")

gdf_F = momepy.nx_to_gdf(F)[1]


coords = {}
for i, j, in enumerate(list(G.nodes)):
    coords[i] = j


lengths = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "length")
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, values=lengths, name="weight")

G = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G, label_attribute='old_label')

# define parameters for input, choose num of random nodes

num_steiners = 200
edge_list = [[int(u), int(v)] for u, v in G.edges()]
node_id = [i for i in range(len(G.nodes))]
prizes = [0]*len(G.nodes)

selection = random.sample(list(range(len(prizes))), num_steiners)

for s in selection:
    prizes[s] = 9999 # some high value to catch no matter what

costs = np.array(list(nx.get_edge_attributes(G, "length").values()))
root = -1
num_clusters = 1

vertices, edges = pcst_fast.pcst_fast(edge_list, prizes, costs, root, num_clusters, "gw", 1)
```

I ran the following code, which takes a roads shapefile and a points shapefile and outputs a path made out of vertices (1D array of ints, node indexes) and edges (1d array of ints, edge indexes). How do I turn those edge indexes back into a shapefile of the path in the rode network? Is there a way to link graph G to the roads shapefile and just keep the edges returned by this code? I can create lines based on the coords attribute to make an output shapefile, but these are just perfectly straight lines with the shape of the road network lost.